# Checking if a NETCDF file already exists

Tags: fortran, netcdf, netcdf4

What's the best way to check whether a given netCDF file exists in Fortran90? I have a Fortran program which simulates several systems and stores the data in a NETCDF file, and I'd like to be able to set it up so that I can run the code with already-existing netCDF files and just append the extra data.

It seems to work with the following:

```
status = nf90_open(filePath, NF90_WRITE, netcdfID)
if (status /= nf90_noerr) then
    new_status = nf90_create(filePath, NF90_NETCDF4, netcdfID)
    ! setup
else
    ! check file has correct dimensions etc
end if
```

But I'd like to be able to be specific about the error, but [the documentation](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs-fortran/f90_datasets.html#f90-nf90_open) isn't very specific about what the error code is when the file already exists.

I've also considered checking the status of the `nf90_create(...)` call, but I don't know how to specify `cmode=NF90_NETCDF4` and `cmode=NF90_NOCLOBBER` at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, when I use NetCDF with Fortran and need to look at the documentation, I look at the C-documentation at https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/modules.html and 'translate' it to the Fortran API (for example replacing the `nc_` with `nf90_`) because the C documentation is far more current than the Fortran one.

There seem to be these possible status results:

- `NF90_NOERR` No error.
- `NF90_EPERM` Attempting to create a netCDF file in a directory where you do not have permission to open files.
- `NF90_ENFILE` Too many files open
- `NF90_ENOMEM` Out of memory.
- `NF90_EHDFERR` HDF5 error. (NetCDF-4 files only.)
- `NF90_EDIMMETA` Error in netCDF-4 dimension metadata. (NetCDF-4 files only.)

None of these suggest that you were opening a file that doesn't exist. Maybe try it out?

But if you only want to know whether the file already exists, why not use Fortran's `INQUIRE` statement?

```
logical :: fileExists
...
inquire(file=filePath, exist=fileExists)
if (fileExists) then
    call nf90_open(
else
    call nf90_create(
end if
```